# stopping accessibility of internal script files via mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, script

Turns out after researching, one site found duplicate content on my website.

The reason is because the unfriendly php file that friendly URLs link to was apparently discovered by a robot and then got spread.

What I want to do is fix this issue without causing a redirect loop.

I'll explain by example:

Currently To redirect the contacts page with mod_rewrite, I use:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ /index2.php?A=CONTACT [L]
```

But the problem is `http://example.com/contact` and `http://example.com/index2.php?A=CONTACT` are both accessible and point to exactly the same page, yet I don't want the latter URL directly accessible in a browser.

I was thinking using something like:

```
RewriteRule ^index2.php$ ??? [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /index2.php?A=CONTACT [L]
```

Because I need to handle the php file but I can't replace the `???` with `/contact` or I'll be creating an endless loop.

I was thinking of adding this to the top to prevent a second round of looping from happening:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

But I'm not sure if that's of any help.

If anyone has run into this situation can someone give me a hand on how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure you got my last ping... I updated the answer with the assumption there was a /contact directory. If not, then it is back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to *redirect* from the "unfriendly" URL to the "friendly" URL, avoiding rewrite loops, you can check against `%{THE_REQUEST}` (which contains the *initial* HTTP request). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?A=CONTACT
RewriteRule ^index2\.php /contact? [R=301,L]
```

This should come *before* the internal rewrite that turns the "friendly" URL into the actual URL.

Since you are using different *case* for the URL parameter ("CONTACT") and the URL-path ("contact") it will be tricky to make this rule more generic without using `RewriteMap` in your *server config* (not .htaccess). Although this could be handled in your code instead.

Comment: @MIke Try this first!!

Comment: w3d's answer seems to help with a question mark added before `[R=301,L]` What I did in my php code however was check the redirect_status variable since it returns a number on any RewriteRule processed. If w3d's idea lowers the overall TTFB of the site then I'll use it instead.

Comment: Ah yes (oops forgot!), the `?` is required at the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution in order to _remove_ the query string (added to answer). (Or you can use the `QSD` flag if using Apache 2.4+). Doing this in Apache config (.htaccess) is going to be quicker and more efficient than handing this over to PHP. You can check `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` in .htaccess as well (it is an Apache environment variable), but it is no better than the above.